# Closing the VBA Editor Window

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to close my Visual Basic Editor window. I couldn't find any perfect code for this. These are the previous suggested codes i have tried,

1) `Application.VBE.MainWindow.Close`
2) `Application.VBE.ActiveWindow.Close`
3) `Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.Window.Close`

If I run any of these codes, i am getting the following Run time error(6068)
"Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted".
Please tell me if there is any solution for this problem.

Comment: Under the Options menu, find the security section and enable programmatic access to Visual Basic project.

Comment: Rachel Hettinger, Thanks that did the work

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ShowVisualBasicEditor = False
```

Comment: That method doesn't seem to be available on Excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

> ##### Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

tested with:

```
Sub hideVBE()
    MsgBox "foo"
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
    MsgBox "bar"
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Its recommended to add a brief explanation of why this answer solve the question.